# Python: Writing numpy arrays with different dimensions to txt file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays with dimensions (81, 5) and (3196, 7) that I need to write to a csv file. The actual desired output would look something like this:

```
81 #This is the len() of the first array
1    2    3    4    5
.
.
81   2    3    4    5
#skip a line
3196 #len() of the second array
1    2    3    4    5    6    7
.
.
3196 2    3    4    5    6    7
```

Where the numbers in the columns are some data (not actually 123456).
I was able to more or less Frankenstein together an array by filling the spaces with np.NaN then replace the NaN values with blank spaces. However I was unable to output the file using the following:

```
np.savetxt(r'path/sample.Data.srv', data, delimiter = '\t', fmt='%.5f')
```

Where I get the error:

> Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.5f   %.5f    %.5f    %.5f    %.5f    %.5f    %.5f')

Probably due to the blank spaces (' ') being a string. fmt='%.5s' works but I need the numbers to be floats. I am still new to python and have always used np.savetxt() since I have never worked with arrays with different shapes before, nor am I familiar with other options to write txt files. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `savetxt` just iterates over the `rows` of the array, and writes each to the file using your `fmt` (or one derived from that and the number of columns).  You could open a file ('wb' mode), and pass that to successive `savetxt` calls, each with a different array.  This has been discussed in previous SO questions.  Think also about how you will read the file.  Most readers don't like different numbers of columns.

Comment: Thank you, do you happen to have a link to the question? I have tried searching before posting this question but I probably didn't word it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you cobbled together an array that looks like (with space in place of None):

```
In [74]: data
Out[74]: 
array([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, None, None],
       [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, None, None],
       [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, None, None],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], dtype=object)
```

But the error has more to do with object dtype

```
In [75]: np.savetxt('test.txt', data, fmt='%.5f')
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f')
```

With the more general `%s` format, this works:

```
In [76]: np.savetxt('test.txt', data, fmt='%s')
In [77]: cat test.txt
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 None None
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 None None
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 None None
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

But this is multiple savetxt that I had in mind:

```
In [79]: with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
    ...:     np.savetxt(f, d[0], fmt='%.5f')
    ...:     f.write(b'\n')
    ...:     np.savetxt(f, d[1], fmt='%.5f')
    ...:     
In [80]: cat test.txt
1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000

0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I was trying to put together something like this after reading your previous comment, but didn't know the code to write an empty line (f.write(b'\n'))...